# How to hide a widget if an editor/admin is connected (Apostrophe CMS and Nunjucks)

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I would like to hide a small view if an editor (or admin) is connected (with Apostrophe).

i want something like this (pseudo-code)

```
{% if not connected %}
{% include "myView.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This will work for many cases:

```
{% if not data.user %}
  {% include "myView.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Or, if you just want to know if the current user can edit the current page or not:

```
{% if not data.page._edit %}
  {% include "myView.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

(This second technique makes sense only for a page template. You didn't mention what sort of template this is, so I thought I'd better point that out.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dummy (empty) template. It works, but I think Apostrophe has a better way :)

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

var res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% include "myView.html" if connected else "dummy.html" %}
    `, {connected: false});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The asker wanted to know how to change the behavior based on whether a user is logged in, and the asker's original if statement is fine; it's obtaining a value for "connected" that they need help on.